# Java applets not working on Cocoa Webview

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, webview, applet

I have java applet ,it is working on safari fine.

But it doesn't working on my cocoa app.

I am trying to display the java applet on webview.

Here is my code.

```
NSString *urlStr = @"https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~matuszek/General/JavaVersionTests/JavaTests.html";

[self.dummywebView.mainFrame loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlStr]]];
```